# How to show the content using side navigation bar in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, sidenav

[image]

Hi All,

I want to display some static content whenever we click any index from the left menu like in the attached image. Also, the content should be on a single page like in this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-annotation-config. Whenever I click the any of the indexes the corresponding content should be visible to the user by scrolling the page. Can anyone suggest me an idea to achieve this using Angular and bootstrap? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing content using Side bar

**.html**

```
<div class="sidebar"> 
   <li (click)=""goToList('content1')>Side bar list 1</li>
</div>
<div id="content1" class="content1">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
goToList(id: any) {
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
         element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
     }
  }
```

Try this Method it will be working fine as you want

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Will try it and let you know my comments

Comment: Welcome !  @Olive let me know if any problem

Comment: Ya it's working perfectly:). Thank you so much. And one more thing i want the side bar on left side and content should be on right side like in the image. Can u pls suggest me an idea to achieve this?

Comment: if possible can u post ur answer here pls

Comment: i will explain very easy way it's very big process may be so i can suggest or show example if you we can contact !

Comment: ya sure can u pls schedule a meeting for this email oliveandrew123@gmail.com

Comment: Okay i will send later